# How to modify navigation menu of the "My Account" page in WooCommerce

Tags: menus, woocommerce-offtopic, navigation

I want to modify the WooCommerce "My Account" left side navigation menu.

For that, I have made changes in the `woocommerce/templates/myaccount/navigation.php`.
The problems with this approach are:

- I can add the new items **only** at the first or last position in the menu. I'd need them at the 2nd and 3rd position instead....
- If WC gets updated, it could change...

What is the best way to customize the WooCommerce "My Account" navigation menu at my convenience?

[image]

Comment: The more detailed answer here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/Customising-account-page-tabs

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For that, you do **not** need to modify the [`woocommerce/templates/myaccount/navigation.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/navigation.php).

The best way to customize the "My Account" navigation menu items is to use:

- [`woocommerce_account_menu_items`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-account-functions.php#L127) filter hook to add new items to the menu.
- [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-slice.php) to reorder them the way you want.

This way, by using `woocommerce_account_menu_items` filter hook, you integrate **perfectly** your own items to WC, indeed:

- Possibility to redefine your own item endpoints via the WC "Account" settings page.
- WC updates automatically the item link's URL when, for example, a modification is done to the permalink settings/structure.

Code example:

```
// Note the low hook priority, this should give to your other plugins the time to add their own items...
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_my_menu_items', 99, 1 );

function add_my_menu_items( $items ) {
    $my_items = array(
    //  endpoint   => label
        '2nd-item' => __( '2nd Item', 'my_plugin' ),
        '3rd-item' => __( '3rd Item', 'my_plugin' ),
    );

    $my_items = array_slice( $items, 0, 1, true ) +
        $my_items +
        array_slice( $items, 1, count( $items ), true );

    return $my_items;
}
```

**Note 1**: The link's url of your items is defined automatically by WC [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/myaccount/navigation.php#L30). To do that, WC simply append the item endpoint defined in the filter above to the "My account" page URL. So define your item endpoints accordingly.

**Note 2**: In your question, it seems like you modified the WooCommerce template directly in core...
`woocommerce/templates/myaccount/navigation.php` 
When you **have to** modify a WC template, the correct way to do it is to duplicate the template's path **relative** to the `woocommerce/templates` folder into your theme/plugin's `woocommerce` folder. For example in our case, you'd have to paste the template into:
`child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/navigation.php`.

Comment: Hello, I'm trying this method, by adding the code into functions.php, but I get the links only in the top navigation, not also in the side menu, any suggestion?

Comment: @alexcr Both the sidebar and header are handled by your theme, not by the plugin WC. WC just implements templates and hooks which are up to theme devs and integrators to include or not.

Answer (score 5):

Well customizing Woocommerce account and adding new items comes in a few steps,

**First Step: Create Links:**

You should use `woocommerce_account_menu_items` filter to modify existing menu items or adding new menu items, for example i add an item called **Wishlist**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', function($items) {
    $items['wishlist'] = __('Wishlist', 'textdomain');

    return $items;
}, 99, 1 );
```

**Note:** I've gone through simplest way, you can use [array_slice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) if you want to put menu item at your desired position.

**P.s:** If you want to remove or modify existing items you can do it like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', function($items) {
    unset($items['downloads']); // Remove downloads item
    $items['orders'] = __('My Orders', 'textdomain'); // Changing label for orders

    return $items;
}, 99, 1 );
```

**Step 2: Add rewrite end points:**

For each item you add you're gonna need to add an endpoint:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'wishlist', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
    // Repeat above line for more items ...
} );
```

Note that after you add new endpoints you need to flush rewrite rules by either going to ***wp-admin/settings/permalinks*** and clicking **update** button or with `flush_rewrite_rules()` function

**Step 3: Display new item content**

To display content for your newly added items you should use `woocommerce_account_{myEndPoint}_endpoint` action, for our example i created a file called `wishlist.php` in my themes directory under `woocommerce/myaccount/` and display it's content like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_wishlist_endpoint', function() {
    wc_get_template_part('myaccount/wishlist');
});
```